# How to ios connect web service and get json data?

Tags: iphone, web-services, ios7, xcode5

When I connect to web services that return Json strings it returns them like XML:

```
2014-02-07 00:17:15.673 Test[791:70b] <\?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<\string xmlns="MBSCafe.Service.ServiceManager">{"query": [{"ID": "01","Name": "food"}]}<\/string>
```

Instead, I want this:

```
{"query": [{"ID": "01","Name": "food"}]}
```

This is my part of code:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://mbsserver/MBSCafeService/ServiceManager.asmx/GetItemTypeList";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSString *myRequestString = @"id="; // Attention HERE!!!!
myRequestString = [myRequestString stringByAppendingString:@"01"];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String] length:[myRequestString length]];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: You check WebService for json response and if in any case if that is not possible then call webservice and convert xml to json with [XMLReader](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure server return response in json format first, you can check it by fidder or other Firefox, Chrome plugins

Comment: when i call this web service in android I can get json object but in iOS it's return like xml.

Answer (score 0):

Test your webservice using the firefox plug-in called "`HTTP resource test`", specify your parameters  there and see what response you are getting. You can find this plug-in using `firefox->tools->HTTP resource test`.